# How can I do a lot of NSURLConnection without cross over all the request?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

Is it possible to do that with NSOperation? I try it but sometime it doesn't work.

For Example the my sequence is :

1. Mark 4 news as read
2. Mark 3 news as read
3. Mark 3 news as read
4. Reload News Source
5. Mark 4 news as read
6. Reload News Source

Sometimes I think that the queue is not respected... how can I do?
thank

EXAMPLE*******

```
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:delegate.reader
                                                                        selector:@selector(setUnread:)
                                                                          object:item];

[delegate.queue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
```

I think that others request like this start after the first 1... but what I want is that the 2nd one starts only when the 1st one is finished...

Comment: Yes, it's possible? Have you even tried it?

Comment: I add an example of my request

Answer (score 0):

You need to create dependencies between operations, so you can have some sort of conditioning like so:

```
[secondOperation addDependency:firstOperation];
[operationQueue addOperation:firstOperation];
[operationQueue addOperation:secondOperation];
```

Comment: and if I don't know wich is the current previous operation?

Comment: current previous? Is it current or the previous?

Comment: my queue is in the appdelegate... a lot of class can add operation in the queue.... so I can't know wich is the previous nsoperation to add as dependency

Comment: Well only you know the order... You can't know which is the current executing operation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CustomNSURLConnection class Like as follows .

CustomNSURLConnection.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
typedef void (^ServiceBlock)(NSString *result);


@interface CustomNSURLConnection : NSURLConnection
@property (nonatomic, copy) ServiceBlock serviceBlock;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *serviceResponseData;

- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate  usingCallback:(ServiceBlock)callBackBlock;
@end
```

CustomNSURLConnection.m

```
#import "CustomNSURLConnection.h"

@implementation CustomNSURLConnection

@synthesize serviceBlock, serviceResponseData;

-(id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate  usingCallback:(ServiceBlock)callBackBlock{
    self = [super initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate];
    if (self) {
        self.serviceBlock = callBackBlock;
        self.serviceResponseData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    return self;  
}


@end
```

WebServiceHitter.h

```
#import "CoffeeshopCustomNSURLConnection.h"



@interface WebServiceHitter : NSObject

    @end
```

WebServiceHitter.m

```
  @interface CoffeeShopWebServiceHitter()
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *responseData;



#pragma mark - NSURLConnection Delegate Methods

- (void)connection:(CustomNSURLConnection *)connectionDb didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    CustomNSURLConnection *specializedNSURLDataConnection = (CustomNSURLConnection *)connectionDb;

    [specializedNSURLDataConnection.serviceResponseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(CustomNSURLConnection *)connectionDb didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
   CustomNSURLConnection *specializedNSURLDataConnection = (CoffeeshopCustomNSURLConnection *)connectionDb;
    [specializedNSURLDataConnection.serviceResponseData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connection:(CustomNSURLConnection *)connectionDb didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(CustomNSURLConnection *)finishedWithConnection {
    CustomNSURLConnection *specializedNSURLConnection = (CustomNSURLConnection*)finishedWithConnection;
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:specializedNSURLConnection.serviceResponseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    specializedNSURLConnection.serviceResponseData = nil;

    specializedNSURLConnection.serviceBlock(responseString); 

}
@end
```

And create your webservice request in webservicehitter files according to your usage

Comment: Seems a bit like overkill or can you come up with a valid argument for why the OP should do this? (I did it once and it worked then is not a valid argument.) How will this solve the OP's question? Why is this a good solution?

Comment: He told that he want the data to separate and connection should pass through a single class so only i preferred this approach

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are looking for a serial operation queue.

Just set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` on the queue to `1` and it will only run one operation at a time.

This should be done before adding the operations to the queue. Note that it only has to be done once and *not* for every operation like I'm showing below.

```
delegate.queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
[delegate.queue addOperation:someOperation];
```

Comment: I'll try this solution... I think that it is what I was looking for... I'll let you know.

Comment: Someone care to comment on the downvote? What makes it a bad answer?